# Bootstrap form validation in a table not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I want to use Bootstrap form validation in a table (the form and the button are in the table).
I figured out that it does not work if I use the `<table>` tag. When removed, the validation works as desired (but the table structure is broken). Does anyone know why it behaves this way and if there is a quick workaround (while keeping the table)?

Removing the `<table>` tag fixes the form validation issues, but I'd like to us a table.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = $('.needs-validation')


  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    console.log(form);
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> ID:</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form method="POST" action="#" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td>User</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="New username" name="username" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a username.
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Confirm</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML. The children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>` or `<th>`. You can't have `<form>` as a child or `<tr>`.

Comment: So either put the form inside a single `<td>`, or put it around the entire `<table>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This fixes the issue. Can you post your answer so I can mark it and close the question.

Comment: If you are new to HTML and still learning I strongly recommend validating your HTML in the future with this tool: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the table with [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  const forms = $('.needs-validation')


  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
    console.log(form);
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.first {
  grid-column: 1;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.second {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="POST" action="#" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="first">ID:</div>
  <label class="second">1</label>
  <div class="first">Username:</div>
  <label class="second">User <input class="form-control" placeholder="New username" name="username" required><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Confirm</button>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a username.</div>
  </label>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```